# How to call a private method of a class in different package

Tags: java

There is a BookView.class that has a private method defined as below

```
  public class BookView{
    private boolean importBook(String epubBookPath){
    //The function that adds books to database.
    }
  }
```

I am trying to call this function from a different package. My code is

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);

        /*Now we add the book information to the sqlite file.*/
        TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        String filename = textView.getText().toString();
        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String epubBookPath = baseDir+filename;
        Log.i("epubBookPath:",epubBookPath); //No errors till here!

        try {
            Method m=BookView.class.getDeclaredMethod("importBook");
            m.setAccessible(true);//Abracadabra 
            //I need help from here! How do i pass the epubBookPath to the private importBook method.
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                CallEPubUIActivity.class);        
        startActivity(in);
    }
```

EDIT:

I found another public method in the jar file which is doing the above work.

```
  public void jsImportBook(String epubBookPath) {
     if (!BookView.this.importBook(epubBookPath))
     return;
   BookView.this.createBookshelf();
  }
```

Comment: Private methods are private for a reason, so no one outside of the class calls them.  You're not going to be able to do this unless you maybe try using reflection and even then I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: Reflection is the way to go, but nobody actually recommends it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880365/any-way-to-invoke-a-private-method

Comment: Read the [Invoking Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) secion of the [Oracle Reflection Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Comment: @cmbaxter I would make it public but it is a class of a jar file. I have got it using the java decompiler. I cannot edit it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to do that you should make it `public` or make a `public` wrapper method it.

If thats not possible, you can work your way around it, but thats ugly and bad and you should have *really* good reasons to do so.

```
public boolean importBook(String epubBookPath){
    //The function that adds books to database.
}
```

or

```
public boolean importBookPublic(String epubBookPath){
    return importBook(epubBookPath);
}
private boolean importBook(String epubBookPath){
    //The function that adds books to database.
}
```

Also note that if you CAN'T access the method directly in a third-party library than it is most likely INTENDED that way. Take a look at the [call hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197229/getting-a-call-hierarchy-in-java) of the `private` method and see if you find a `public` method that does the call to the `private` one and that also does what you need.

Libraries are often designed in a way that a `public` method does some checking (all Parameters given, authenticated etc.) and then pass the call to the `private` method to do the actual work. You almost never want to work around that process.

Comment: dont you think you need to specify return for importBook(epubBookPath) inside of public method.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I would make it public but it is a class of a jar file. I have got to it using the java decompiler. I cannot edit it. 
Is there a way i can edit it? 
Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: @Bhavyanshu Most likely there is a intended way to achieve that result and the method is `private` by design. As long as you don't know why its private, you should not work your way around this. Have a look at the call hierarchy and have a look from where that method gets called, then decide if one of the `public` methods that do call that private one are capable of performing your task for you. Then use them. If that fails, have a look at where the jar comes from and if the original code is somewhere (or you can contact the original creator). Them let them fix it. Reflection is last resort.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Okay as you just said, there is a public function being called from a javascript file. Check the edit in the question.

Answer (score 9):

With reflection, you'll need an instance of BookView to invoke the method with (unless it's a static method).

```
BookView yourInstance = new BookView();
Method m = BookView.class.getDeclaredMethod("importBook");
m.setAccessible(true);//Abracadabra 
Boolean result = (Boolean) m.invoke(yourInstance, "A Path"); // pass your epubBookPath parameter (in this example it is "A Path"
```

The method you are looking for is [`Method#invoke(Object, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: Does this method work with importBook() as a private function?

Comment: @Hao Yes, `setAccessible` permits that.

Answer (score 2):

Use reflection to get you method and set `Accessible` as `true`, **then invoke the method using `BookView` Object instance and required parameters(path string)** using statement as below:

```
     Boolean result = (Boolean)method.invoke(bookObject, epubBookPath);
```

Sample code as below:

```
Method method = BookView.getDeclaredMethod("importBook");
method.setAccessible(true);
Boolean result = (Boolean)method.invoke(bookObject, epubBookPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Private methods cannot be accessed outside the class it is defined.
Make it Public.